# URL Rewriting vulnerability

Tags: security, url, url-rewriting

We modified our Session handling from cookie based to URL Rewriting. By doing this the session id gets transmitted as part of the URL.

Now there is a vulnerability issue, where whoever uses this URL will be able to log in into the system.

To resolve this issue we have done the following

[1] A HTTP Session Listener has been created to maintain list of HTTP sessions. 
Listener reacts on the events when session are created or destroyed.

[2] A Session Filter has been created to verify HTTP Session and check its integrity against HTTP Request attributes
Session will be invalidated in case Request attributes (identifying the client origin) do not match original attributes stored with session. (to block the session hijack attempt)

However i think that this has a gap, when you are trying to access over a proxy etc.

Is there any other effective solution for this?

Also we cannot use third party libraries to resolve this because of the nature of the produce.

Comment: Consider asking the question at http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please do not cross post - ask to migrate by flagging for moderator attention. Other URL: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/62767/8340

Comment: I've stopped at your first line. `{°_°}` Why did you do that?

Answer (score 1):

So you need to be doubly careful with session ID likes this: users share URLs! The definitive advice on the subject comes from OWASP:

- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet

But I think you should consider the following additional controls:

- Rotating the session key on each request.  This is only practical with simple web applications though.  It'll cause problems undoubtedly with AJAX and might be difficult to manage if the user is likely to open a second tab on the application.
- Shorter timeouts.

I am presuming that in the 'HTTP Request Attributes' you mention you are already picking up the User-agent, source IP address and invalidating the session if these are inconsistent.

If you are using SSL it might be possible to do a great solution where the session ID is tied to the SSL connection (Apache, for example, exposes this in a SSL_SESSION_ID environment variable).  But this information might not be available to your application.